# htaccess mod_rewrite two query string parameters to path format

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

How would I change

```
http://example.com/?sort=top&time=variable
```

to

```
http://example.com/top/variable
```

`&time=variable` may not always be used.

My current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?showcase/(.*?)/?$ /showcase.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /showcase\.php\?id=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?showcase\.php$ /showcase/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

rewrites `http://example.com/showcase.php?id=int` to `http://example.com/showcase/int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is in the `.htaccess` files, use `^` instead of `^/?`. For your particular case, you can modify/add to the existing redirection as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(top)(?:/([^/])+)?/?$ /?sort=$1&time=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?sort=(top)(?:&time=([^\s&]+))? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot. I honestly can't wrap my head around writing this stuff, it seems too complex